# Can I setup default CMake cache variables to apply for all projects?

Tags: cmake

There are several settings I need to provide to `CMake` which are the same on every project.  It gets annoying having to specify these on the command line every time I blow away my build area and start again.

For example:

    `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${HOME}/local`

Is there a way to provide values for common settings like `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` so that they are applied to all projects by default?

Answer (score 2):

You may create "initial-cache" script

**~/default.cmake**:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Build type")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX $ENV{HOME}/local CACHE PATH "Installation prefix")
```

and pass it to cmake as with `-C` option:

```
cmake -C ~/default.cmake ..
```

More info about `-C` option in [cmake(1) documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html#options).

---

As for using these setting by **default** (that is, without any additional options to cmake), I don't know a clear way for doing this.

You may create wrapper script like `default-cmake`, which calls `cmake` with original plus additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create an initial `CMakeCache.txt` file that exactly contains those two variables:

```
$ cat CMakeCache.txt
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=~/local
```

Upon the next cmake run, the `CMakeCache.txt` will contains the remaining of the cmake run. You do not need to pass any additional flags to cmake, but it will scratch your inital `CMakeCache.txt` (thus you need to add it to .gitignore).